# Unable to deploy Hubot on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hubot

I deployed a Hubot instance on Heroku last month (Feb 13) with hubot 2.4.6.

Today I wanted to add a new script and got a compile error when deploying back to heroku.
Before updating I tried to deploy a fresh new hubot following the wiki instructions leads to the exact same error, here are the logs :

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23/23), 10.58 KiB, done.
Total 23 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.10.0
       Using npm version: 1.1.65
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optparse/1.0.3
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot-scripts
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/optparse/1.0.3
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optparse/-/optparse-1.0.3.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot-scripts
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot-scripts/-/hubot-scripts-2.4.2.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot/-/hubot-2.4.8.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/optparse/-/optparse-1.0.3.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot-scripts/-/hubot-scripts-2.4.2.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hubot/-/hubot-2.4.8.tgz
       npm ERR! cb() never called!
       npm ERR! not ok code 0
 !     Failed to install --production dependencies with npm
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:radiant-taiga-1655.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:radiant-taiga-1655.git'
```

Now Hubot is 2.4.8.
Anybody having the same issue or am I missing something ?

Comment: I have same problem today and trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had the same problem. We fixed it by changing node version to 0.8.21 in package.json.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "= 0.8.21",
  "npm": "1.1.x"
}
```

Comment: Yes it did fix the issue ! thanks. I guess this is a very temporary situation, so I will try soon to unfreeze the node version.

Comment: This fixes the deploy, but the Node.js app still fails to build for me when tailing the heroku logs :(

Answer (score 0):

So I've been having similar errors on NPM 1.2.9, nodejs 0.9.12 and `npm cache clean` fixed everything.

After `npm update` fails, run `npm cache clean` and then run `npm update` again.